# new dataframe within if statement. Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Here is the the part of the code I am having issues with:

```
for x in range(len(df['Days'])):
    if df['Days'][x]>0 and df['Days'][x]<=30: 
        b = df['Days'][x]
b
```

The output I get is b = 14 which is the last value where the if statement holds in the column of the dataframe. I am trying to get ALL the values of the column in which the if statement holds to be held in "b" rather than just the last value alone.

Comment: You probably want to initialize `b` as a `list()` before the for loop and then `b.append(df['Days'][x]` in your if statement.

Comment: Please add some sample data to this question and expected output.  The way you are accessing data in your data frame is unconventional.  You should stay way from using chained indexing.  If you have '][' in your statement then you are probably chained indexing.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is make a list instead and append b to it.

```
my_vals = []
for x in range(len(df['Days'])):
    if df['Days'][x]>0 and df['Days'][x]<=30: 
        b = df['Days'][x]
        my_vals.append(b)
my_vals
```

In your code, you are changing `b` in every iterration and so it only stores the most recent value. In the future when you are trying to store multiple values, do so in a different Data Type.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the filtering functionality of pandas and use

`values = df.loc[(df['Days'] >= 0) & (df['Days'] <= 30)]`

If you want the values as a Series instead of a DataFrame use

`values_series = values['Days']`

If you want the values as a list instead of a Series use

`values_list = list(values_series)`